# How to manipulate two data values in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In `Vue.JS` I have

```
data() {
  return {
     name: 'John',
     sentence: "Hi my name is {{ name }}",
  };
},
```

In my `HTML` I have

`<h2>{{ sentence}}</h2>`

But the output is

> Hi my name is {{name}}

The `{{name}}` isn't being replaced. I am taking this approach because the user can fetch different sentences from a `db`, so the name has to e dynamically changeable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `sentence` as computed property :

```
data(){
   return {
         name: 'John',      
      };
   },
computed:{
   sentence(){
     return  `Hi my name is ${ this.name }`
   }
}
```

or you could do that when you receive the data by using a regex  :

```
data(){
   return {
         name: 'John',  
         sentence :  "Hi my name is {{ name }}"  
      };
   },
...
this.sentence = res.data.sentence.replace(/{{.*name.*}}/,this.name);
```

Comment: If sentece is comming from database then you cant do it like this

Comment: Yes you're right, I think that name which is coming from db

Comment: How did you receive the data from db?

Comment: Sent Get request to DB and it returns something like:
```Nice to meet you {{name}}```

Comment: please add the example to your question

Comment: I need to see the code on how do you receive that?

Comment: ```axios.get(`${appURL}/api/`).then((res) => {
            if (res.data.success) {
               this.sentence = res.data.sentence;
            }
         });```

Comment: I can't, your answer doesnt work - you CAN'T update computed properties like this!

Comment: I didn't mean to replace the computed property, i edited my answer to remove any confusing stuff

Answer (score 1):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'John',
      sentence: 'Hi my name is {{ name }}',
      newSentence: 'Thanks {{ name }}!'
    }
  },

  computed: {
    output() {
      return this.sentence.replace(/{{.*name.*}}/, this.name)
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
   changeSentence() {
      this.sentence = this.newSentence
      this.newSentence = 'try anything {{ name }}'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ output }}
  
  <input type="text" v-model="newSentence" />
  <button @click.prevent="changeSentence()">Change</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Building ontop of Emīls Gulbis answer, Then you can update the value with a watcher when the sentence changes from the database like so:

```js
  watch: {
    sentence(newValue) {
      this.sentence = newValue.replace('{{ name }}', this.name)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access data properties like {{name}} until the data method has returned, also {{this.name}} will return undefined.

To achieve that you need to use computed property:

```
computed:{
   sentence(){
     return  `Hi my name is ${ this.name }`
   }
}
```

Or

directly inside the template:

```
<h2>Hi my name is {{ name }}</h2>
```